# onsubmit="return formValidate():" if false also the form submits

Tags: javascript, html, forms

This is an example.html file

```
<form name="test1" onsubmit="return formValidate();" action="test.html" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name"/>
<input type="submit" value ="Submit"/>
```

Here is a code of html file where in it has a text field and a submit button.
The below code is code of test.html where the form proceeds after successful validation.

```
<body>
    <p>hii </p>
</body>
```

My javascript function to validate form is as follows : formValidate.js

```
function formValidate(){
    var uname=document.test1.name; 
    if(alpha(uname))
    {
    }
    return false;
}
function alpha(uname){
    var pattern=/(?![0-9]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
    if(uname.value.match(pattern))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Invalid input: only numeric not accepted");
        uname.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is my validate code where if it returns false it should throw an alert message saying invalid input. that is working fine. But when it returns false I want the form to not get submitted to the next page. 
How do i do it?

Comment: You have a typo: it should probably be an equation sign instead of a dash here: `var uname = document.test1.name;`

Comment: typing mistake sir thanks for notifying :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<form name="test1" action="test.html" methos="post"  onsubmit="return formValidate();">
<input type="text" name="name"/>
<input type="submit" value ="Submit"/>
</form>


function formValidate()
{
    var uname=document.test1.name; 
     var pattern=/(?![0-9]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
    if(uname.value.match(pattern))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Invalid input: only numeric not accepted);
        uname.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the same sir but it is not working. If the validation fails and returns false to the onsubmit it still directs me to test.html page which i don't want. I want it to stay in the same page if validation fails.

Comment: then check it returns false or true

Comment: Its returning false only because the alert message correctly displays the message saying invalid input. Some problem with onsubmit

Comment: you just alert something in else part of if(alpha(uname))
    {
       //code
       return true;
    }
    else
      return false;

Comment: try my answer.Change in that

Answer (score 0):

Add to onsubmit event:

```
<form onsubmit="return formValidate(event);"
```

And you have syntax errors in your code. I fixed them, try this:

```
function formValidate(e){
    var uname = document.test1.name;// fix - to =

    if(alpha(uname)) {
        //some code here?
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }

}

function alpha(uname){
    var pattern = /(?![0-9]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;//remove *
     if(uname.value.match(pattern)) {
        return true;
     } else {
         alert("Invalid input: only numeric not accepted);
         uname.focus();
         return false;
     }
 }
```

Comment: I fixed the syntax sir the validatiion is happening perfectly but while returnimg if its false also the formm is redirected to next page

Comment: Thank u sir . Do i add the onsubmit to the form tag or the input tag of submit sir?

Answer (score 0):

```
   var uname = document.getElementsByName('name');
```

You get the array uname with its only member at position[0].

```
     if (alpha(uname[0]))
       {
            return true;
       }else{
            return false;
       }
```

etc  ....  It Works!